# Android studio AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

I am using sockets and im getting data continuously in background using Asynctask.

I send this data to `onProgressUpdate()` with `publishProgress()`and I would like to know if there is a way to get the data from function `onProgressUpdate()` or send it to another class, because where I do need to use this data is in another class. At least, is this possible?

I have a .java, in this .java I have 2 public classes:

First one is a class where I use this Asynctask in background to get socket info.

In the second public class I use OpenGL and I need to use that data.

Thank you

Comment: So you want to do this at the time when back process is incomplete, right?

Comment: yes, getting publishProgress data in the OpenGl class

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You define the type of the array passed between `doInBackground()` and `onProgressUpdate()`. You can just publish the progress and consume it that way.

```
new AsyncTask<...,MyDataObject,...>() {...}.execute();
```

Alternatively, you can create a publish-subscribe interface between the thread running `dIB()` and whatever thread is consuming it.

Not that `AsyncTask` isn't intended to be used for long-running operations. It's meant to be a relatively quick one-shot. You'll need to consider running your task on a dedicated executor so as not to block the one serial executor that's used by default for all other instances of `AsyncTask`. E.g.,

```
executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo can do this with `publishProgress()` method and you can call this method from `doInBackground()` and this method can be called at any time when you need to get your data.

Then get data what you want from `params` and store it in public variable of Asynctask and access it from another class.

This may be work.